# conectar 2 pc a una misma base de datos atraves de mysql xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

tengo una aplicación de escritorio programada en c# y necesito que 2 pc se conecten a una misma base de datos por la red local creada desde el un dispositivo android.

pc con el la aplicacion(cliente) : 192.168.43.181

pc con la BBDD : 192.168.43.172

cambie la linea configuracion de my.ini

```
# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address = 0.0.0.0 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6
```

cree un nuevo usuario

```
Usuario : sebastian
Host : 192.168.43.181 (IP del cliente)
Password : yyyyy

cadena de conexion(cliente)
string conString = "server=192.168.43.172; database=nestrada; Uid=sebastian; pwd=yyyyy;";
```

pero el pc cliente no logra conectarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comprueba que la dirección tiene permiso para el acceso al servidor de la base de datos. A la hora de crear el usuario, se debe dar permiso por IP o por equipo

Comment: en el host: puse la direccion del equipo (cliente);

Comment: y deshabilite el firewall de los 2 equipos para realizar la prueba.

Comment: Puedes poner un patallazo del a creación del usuario?

Comment: captura de pantalla añadida..

Comment: en el host debe ir la ip del cliente o servidor?

Comment: host no es la IP del servidor?

Comment: en el host actualmente tengo puesta la ip del cliente(donde tengo el programa en c#)

Comment: En principio parece que esta bien creado. Prueba a cambiar el servidor del usuario sebastian por `%` o por `192.168.43.%`

Comment: ya me funciono. tenia un error en el host.

Comment: podrías decirme como lo solucionaste?

Answer (score 0):

primero debes de crear un usuario con los privilegios.. 
despues debes de asignarle una IP fija...

ejemplo.

user1.

CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contrasena';

user2.

CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contrasena';

despues tienes que agregar los privilegios para cada usuario.

user1.
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'nombre_usuario1'@'localhost'; 
[en el localhost va la ip que le vas asignar al usuario 1]

user2.
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'nombre_usuario1'@'localhost'; 
[en el localhost va la ip que le vas asignar al usuario 2]

y ya teniendo eso en tu manejador de base de datos.

tienes que agregar en el codigo.

el usuario con la ip que le asignastes en el manejador de BD.

(esto se hace para ambos usuarios)

te recomiendo que lo hagas en modo consola mysql console..

espero que te haya servido...

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto los pasos que deberías hacer:

1. Crear un usuario en la base de datos de mysql.
2. Hacer un ipconfig en el equipo donde tienes xampp para saber la ip de ese equipo.
3. en el equipo cliente acceder a la url: http:/ipdondeestamysql
4. si te sale la página de localhost entonces ya tienes un mundo ganado.
5. Conecta tu C# a mysql con los datos del usuario. Nota:aqui en el nombre del servidor, debes poner tu ip no localhost. Aquí hay un ejemplo: [introducir la descripción del vínculo aquí](https://codigosdeprogramacion.com/2020/01/08/conexion-de-csharp-a-base-de-datos-en-mysql/)
6. Compila tu aplicación para que se genere tu archivo .exe
7. Pasa este archivo al equipo cliente.
8. Abre tu aplicación y confirma que se puede conectar.

Espero que te sirva, saludos y Dios te bendiga.